# Errors in References for project VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, dll, reference

I am working on several projects that require me to migrate from VB6 to VB.net. However, after migrating to VB.net, error occur in my project's references as image below.

[image]

I notice that the path for references is null. Is there anything I can do about it? Thank you

Comment: Remove the reference and add it again.

Comment: Yes. I already done that. It works just fine. Thank you Sir